# What to do when raid 0 errer: Following Arrays have missing required members and cannot be ... Array#0-RAID-0

Tags: raid, ibm, raid0

here are the tried status:
It is a raid 0 configuration and have 2 disks.

When using IBM ServeRAID Configuration Utility, there are three options: 
1. Array Configuration Utility  : see below
2. SerialSelect Utility         : not used
3. Disk Utilities               : checked, one disk has a sector defect and reassigned block

1. Array Configuration Utility:
(1). Manage Arrays                : No Arrays present.
(2). Create Array                 : No free drive space availiable or too many arrays on the same device! Please delete one or more Arrays to free drive space
(3). Initialize Drives            : I want data, so didn't try
(4). Rescan Drives                : Nothing happens
(5). Secure Erase Drives          : I want data, so didn't try

I looked the 'Best Practices and Maintenance Information' from IBM, it seems i can run repair in create array, but when i select 'create array' i got that error, cannot continue.

Is it possible to recovery data from this raid?

Thanks for help!

update:
Tried Runtime **RAID Reconstructor**:
Built disk image, guessed raid parameter, saved virtual disk image. 
Now using **Captain Nemo Pro** to get some data out of disk image. 
Recovered main data from raid 0, try raid 1 or make raid0 only for read next time.

Comment: RAID 0 does not have any redundancy of data. If any part of a RAID 0 array fails then all the data is lost. This is spelt out clearly in the specs for this RAID level along with a plea *not to use* RAID 0 unless you understand the limitations and risks of using it in pretty much every bit of RAID documentation I've read ever. Hopefully you have backups because you're pretty much boned if you don't.

Comment: RAID 0 = amount of data you'll get back if the RAID fails. There's no redundancy.

Comment: The next step is to replace the failed disk and then restore your backups.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have had a drive failure.

> Is it possible to recovery data from this raid?

No. At least not with the tools you have available.

RAID 0 has ZERO redundancy and ZERO protection for your data in the event of a disk failure (or someone inadvertently pulling a drive out while the system is running).

As others have said, replace the drive, re-create the array, and restore from your backups.

If you have no backups ***shame on you*** - you should know better if the data is really important. Your best chance of recovering the data would be to box up both drives and ship them off to a data recovery company with a description of what happened *and everything you've done to them to try to restore the data*. They might be able to recover some of the data from the array, depending on the nature of the failure.